# airflow pass parameter from cli

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is there a way to pass a parameter to:

```
airflow trigger_dag dag_name {param}
```

?

I have a script that monitors a directory for files - when a file gets moves into the target directory I want to trigger the dag passing as a parameter the file path.

Answer (score 19):

you can pass it like this:

```
airflow trigger_dag --conf {"file_variable": "/path/to/file"} dag_id
```

Then in your dag, you can access this variable using templating as follows:

```
{{ dag_run.conf.file_variable }}
```

If this doesn't work, sharing a simple version of your dag might help in getting better answers.

Comment: what if you dont want to use templating...?

Comment: @melchoir55 I played some trick on non-template cases. Setting up a global variable, say `param`, at the top of the DAG definition file, `param = "{{dag_run.conf.get('file_variable')}}"`. Then you're able to use the `param` variable anywhere in the file.

Answer (score 15):

yes you can. Your Dag should have a Dag and a Bask Task like this:

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operators import BashOperator

args = {'start_date':datetime.now(),
        'owner':'airflow',}
dag = DAG(
      dag_id='param_dag', 
      default_args=args,
      schedule_interval=None)

bash_task=BashOperator(
     task_id="bash_task" 
     bash_command= 'bash ~/path/bashscript.sh {{ dag_run.conf["parameter"] if dag_run else "" }} ', 
    //bashscript your script you want to run and the dag_run.conf will hold the parameter you want to pass
     dag=dag)
```

Now on your command line just type the command:

```
 airflow trigger_dag dag_id --conf '{"parameter":"~/path" }'
```

Comment: My task is a PythonOperator, not a BashOperator

Comment: @bsd example with [PythonOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652192/accessing-configuration-parameters-passed-to-airflow-through-cli)