# Overwrite Airflow DAG parameter using CLI

Tags: airflow

Given the following DAG:

```py
import logging
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="dag_foo",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 2, 28),
    default_args={"owner": "Airflow", "params": {"param_a": "foo"}},
    schedule_interval="@once",
    catchup=False
)


def log_dag_param(param):
    logging.info(param)


with dag:
    DummyOperator(task_id="dummy") >> PythonOperator(
        python_callable=log_dag_param, op_args=[dag.params["param_a"]]
    )
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to overwrite an existing DAG parameter using the CLI. I'm aware of the [`airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun.conf`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html#airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun.conf), [`--conf`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#Named%20Arguments_repeat10) parameter and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363243/airflow-pass-parameter-from-cli) approach but I'm looking how I could overwrite a DAG parameter instead of a conf value.

Comment: I do not think you can pass `params`.